# How to remove private from Cache-Control through web.config or IIS settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, httpresponse

I tried many ways to remove private value from cache-control HTTP Response Header, I made it possible through global.asax file but unfortunately I was asked to make this possible either through web.config or IIS settings. Can anyone help me out in resolving this issue.

I tried below code, but didn't work. I am getting private

`<add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, s-maxage=0" />`

Answer (score -1):

You can add a response header by the following steps:

1. Open your IIS Manager, navigate to the level you want to manage.
2. In Features View, Double click “HTTP Respond Headers” feature.
3. Click “Add…” on the Actions Panel

Fill in the pop-up window:
Name: Cache-Control
Value: no-cache

[image: Screenshot]

OR

You could use the codes below in web.config.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Regards,
Jalpa.

Comment: I tried both the options, but still Cache-Control shows private, after adding Http Response header entry, it appends "no-cache, no-store" but private is still there, how to remove that?